# How to index these queries effectively

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, indexing

I have an area of my app where a lot of complex queries are being performed, returning 10s of records per page out of a table of 1000s. Here are some samples.

```
SELECT `tasks`.* FROM `tasks` WHERE (`tasks`.company_id = 21) AND (employee_id IS NULL) AND (status != 'Complete') AND (status != 'Cancelled') ORDER BY scheduled desc LIMIT 0, 30;

SELECT `tasks`.* FROM `tasks` WHERE (`tasks`.company_id = 21) AND (employee_id = 0) AND (status != 'Complete') AND (status != 'Cancelled') AND (scheduled IS NOT NULL) AND (scheduled > '2011-03-28' AND scheduled < '2011-09-28');

SELECT `tasks`.* FROM `tasks` WHERE (`tasks`.employee_id = 27) AND (status != 'Complete') AND (status != 'Cancelled') ORDER BY scheduled desc LIMIT 0, 30
```

`employee_id` and `status` are always present; `company_id` is nearly always present, and `scheduled` is just the default ordering, which the user can change.

I tried these indexes:

```
# ignored for some reason - did not seem to build successfully in the db
add_index :tasks, [:company_id, :employee_id, :status, :scheduled]

# db favorite, but often results in FILESORT
add_index :tasks, [:employee_id, :status, :scheduled]
```

What is the best way to deal with my problem and reduce the number of FILESORTS I'm getting on these queries?

Please let me know if I can provide any more detailed information.

Comment: What datatypes are in `tasks.*` and how many columns?  More specifically, are any of them TEXT or BLOB fields?

Comment: Basically we've run into the same issue before and it was because we had TEXT fields in our select.  As soon as we took those fields out of the query and loaded them on-demand, per-record, the problem disappeared.

Comment: @d11wtq - I have 6 `text` fields in my table but none are part of these queries. Are these fields I need to extract to another table to get the indexing working?

Comment: @d11wtq - The fields featured in my question are 2 `integer`, 1 `string`, and 1 `datetime` (scheduled).

Comment: But because your query does a `SELECT *`, the fields are pulled from the database anyway.  Either limit the fields returned (not sure how you do that with ActiveRecord, but it's easy with DataMapper) or split those into a separate table :)

Comment: @sscirrus..your query seems to select `tasks.*`, so the text fields will be selected..you can use `:select` clause in AR to select required fields only.

Comment: @d11wtq, @rubyprince - now the only problem left is doing a `select` with `include`...

Comment: Is add `:include` causing it to use filesort again?  This usually happens when the association is such that the primary key of the first table in your select is NOT the key used in the joins, such as when selecting parents of children.  The only solution(s) are to try and reverse the order in which you select, or to avoid eager-loading those joins.  I think once you're reaching this level of query optimization, you need to consider by-passing AR.

Comment: @d11wtq - as far as I'm aware, Rails 3 doesn't do selects and includes together.

Comment: @sscirrrus...is `tasks` query initlialised by `:include`, I mean are you doing something like this `SomeModel.some_scope :include => :tasks`? Then you are right, you cannot do select on `tasks`. If you are doing AR query directly on Task model or doing a join, you can specify in `select`. You can consider replacing your `include` with `joins` if that is the case. (But you will not get the model properties of Task). can you also paste the code which is causing this query?